# Add a bottom toolbar in console in Python

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface

I want to create a python script, that just print some text lines occasionally. At the bottom of the outputs should always be a toolbar. The text of the toolbar should be changeable.

[image]

The image is taken from the bottom toolbar section of python-prompt-toolkit. Instead of having an input, I want to print multiple lines, while the toolbar stays on the bottom.

Comment: What you need is async callable that will detect size console window's size change (on Unix you can use `signal`'s `sigwinch`, while on Windows if pure Python you will need to either detect size change after needed functions or time, or run it in Thread for constant (but also memory-heavy) option. Then function should detect current cursor (not mouse) position and save it. Then calculate lines and rows needed to reach bottom (better use alternative buffer or set buffer size to window size) and print toolbar. Then it should return to saved coordinates.

Comment: Try to read **prompt-toolkit**'s source code to see how they do it